# how to create display schemas for Many to Many realationships FastAPI and SQLAlchemy with extra data in the assosiation table

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

So working on a project in order to learn FastAPI and SQLAlchemy and I am trying to get the display schema for the data to work only showing the relevant info from the association table.

I have my database models setup as follows.

```
class ServiceHelpers(Base):
    __tablename__ = "service_helpers"
    user_id :Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True)
    service_id : Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("services.id"), primary_key=True)
    role : Mapped[Optional[str]]
    user : Mapped["DbUser"] = relationship(back_populates="role_associations")
    # service : Mapped["DbService"] = relationship(back_populates='role_associations')
    

class DbUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
    services: Mapped[List["DbService"]] = relationship(
        secondary="service_helpers", back_populates="helpers"
    )
    role_associations : Mapped[List["ServiceHelpers"]] = relationship(back_populates='user')

class DbService(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'services'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    date = Column(String)
    title = Column(String)
    serviceplan = Column(String)
    helpers: Mapped[List["DbUser"]] = relationship(
        secondary="service_helpers", back_populates="services"
    )
```

This all seems to work fine.
My display schemas are setup as follows.

```
class ServiceHelpers(BaseModel):
    role : str

class Service(BaseModel):
    date : str
    title :str
    serviceplan : str
    # role_associations : List[ServiceHelpers]
    class Config:
        from_attributes = True

class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: str
    role_associations : List[ServiceHelpers]
    class Config:
        from_attributes = True


class ServiceDisplay(Service):
    helpers: List[User]


class ServiceHelpers(BaseModel):
    role : str

class UserDisplay(User):
    services: List[Service]
```

Now a user can be involved in many services and can have a different role in each service and a service can have a number of different services.

Currently when i get a list of services I get the following output.

```
[
  {
    "date": "Service",
    "title": "Service",
    "serviceplan": "Service",
    "helpers": [
      {
        "username": "Test",
        "email": "test",
        "role_associations": [
          {
            "role": "Speaker"
          },
          {
            "role": "PA"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "username": "test 2",
        "email": "Test 2",
        "role_associations": [
          {
            "role": "Video"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "Service 2",
    "title": "Service 2",
    "serviceplan": "Service 2",
    "helpers": [
      {
        "username": "Test",
        "email": "test",
        "role_associations": [
          {
            "role": "Speaker"
          },
          {
            "role": "PA"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Ideally I would like for only the role the user/helper is involved with for that specific service being displayed in stead of all there roles in all services. eg.

```
[
  {
    "date": "Service",
    "title": "Service",
    "serviceplan": "Service",
    "helpers": [
      {
        "username": "Test",
        "email": "test",
        "role_associations": [
          {
            "role": "Speaker"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "username": "test 2",
        "email": "Test 2",
        "role_associations": [
          {
            "role": "Video"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "Service 2",
    "title": "Service 2",
    "serviceplan": "Service 2",
    "helpers": [
      {
        "username": "Test",
        "email": "test",
        "role_associations": [
          {
            "role": "PA"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Any questions to help clarify please ask.